# Differences and commonalities between publishing an ebook and a paper book

Tags: publishing

Publishing a paper book, for example, requires paper, publishing an ebook usually requires an online store. Both require one or more writer(s). What are the (other) commonalities and differences in the publishing process (including especially those elements which influences the price)?

Comment: I believe this question is in scope and not overly broad.  A simple comparison of to methods with measurable attributes.

Comment: I suspect there are many steps in the publishing of a book so that this will end up too broad. For one view of the steps [this view](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/2010/02/cmap-2-how-books-are-made.html) lists 13 steps for a paper book

Answer (score 3):

actually also publishing a paper book requires a store :-)

Off the top of my head, here there are some differences:

- An ebook has no hard constraints in length: there is more freedom in deciding how long it would be.
- Since an ebook is not printed, there is no minimum number of copies to prepare. Note that printing technologies differ wildly according to the number of copies printed; this means that you have to plan in advance the size of the run.
- With an ebook you don't need place to store the printed copies.
- An ebook is easier to search in for a specific passage.

On the other side:

- With a paper book you have full control of the positioning of text in your pages. (True, if you publish your ebook as a pdf you would have the same control, but usually this defeats the advantages of having an ebook)
- (for non-fiction) A paper book is easier to browse and to bookmark.

Comment: These are differences between the two and not about differences in the publishing process.

Comment: There actually are constraints of length and storage for e-books; it's just that the cost of storing them on a server and the added delivery time (of a bigger e-book) are minimal compared to the print equivalents.

Comment: a paper book has also *minimum* lenght constraints, however.

Comment: @Mark: please define "publishing process", then.

Comment: How and who does work in getting a book published. On second thoughts these might be relevant but they do not cover whatI quoted thus even more so this question is too broad